# How to get ocean waypoints to draw the routes in the Ocean(water surface) with javascript

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, javascript

I am working on implementing the Google Maps API in a web application to represent the routes between the source port to destination port in the ocean.But in order to draw the routes in the sea/ocean apart from (from&To) port coordinates,i need the sea route waypoints which will be useful to plot the route line on the sea/ocean only.

I would like to know how to plot the route in the sea between two ports(From & To) coordinates and how to receive its way points

So Could anyone suggest me the relevant Javascript API or any alternative solution

Thanks in advance......

Comment: What do you certainly want? Automated routing only on water? Or manual plotting of waypoints/route?

Comment: What you seem to need first is a map of sea route waypoints, which is not really on-topic on SO.... I'm sure there are better places to ask for something like that

Comment: I need the same for iOS/Android..Please help me out if anyone has done this task..